# Proving $ \lVert x \rVert := (\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})^{1/2}=\sup\limits_{s \in \mathbb S ^{n-1}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}s_{i}x_{i}$?

Tags: real-analysis

As above, does it hold true that

$$ \lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert := \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}} =\sup\limits_{s \in \mathbb S ^{n-1}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}s_{i}x_{i}=\sup\limits_{s \in \mathbb S ^{n-1}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}s_{i}x_{i}=:\sup\limits_{s \in \mathbb S ^{n-1}}\langle s,x\rangle$$

I am unsure whether this is not just simply an application of Riesz representation, but I am unsure. Note that $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ here denotes the set of unit vectors in $\mathbb R^{n}$, i.e. $u \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}\iff \lvert \lvert u \rvert \rvert = 1$

Comment: Please do not use subject lines that consist of almost nothing but MathJax. It messes up navigation shortcuts. Also, display-style formulas that are too tall or short tend to mess up the displays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it holds. From the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality you have

$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_is_i\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\right)^{1/2}$$
for every $(s_1,\dots,s_n)\in\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. And by choosing
$$s_i=\frac{x_i}{\|x\|}$$
where $\|x\|=\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\right)^{1/2}$
if $x_i\neq 0$ and $s_i=0$ otherwise, you obtain equality, which shows that the supremum is in fact a maximum.